# Why the `stdin` of current progress inflence the behaviour of the command invoked by `popen()`?

Tags: c, pipe, popen

As per the manual of `popen`, which says that[emphasis mine]:

> The popen() function opens a process by creating a pipe, forking, and invoking the shell.  Since a pipe is by definition unidirectional, ***the type argument may specify only reading or writing, not both; the resulting stream is correspondingly read-only or write-only***.

As per the statements above, there is no way to both write and read to the file stream returned by `popen`. So I take it for granted that the `stdin` of current process would not influence the behaviour of the shell command which is passed as parameter for `popen()`.

But it's really out of my expectation when running the program below.

Here is the code snippet code:

```
//filename pipe_cmd.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ret = 0;
    FILE* file = popen("ssh -t jhone@192.168.1.51  bash -c 'top' ", "r");

    int fd = fileno(file);
    char buffer[1024*100];
    
    if(NULL != file)
    {
        while (true) {
            memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
            int ret_read = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            
            if (ret_read > 0) {
              printf("%s", buffer);
            } else if (0 == ret_read) {
              ret = 0;
              break;
            } else {
              ret = -1;
              break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return ret;
}
```

The code snippet is compiled by `gcc pipe_cmd.c -o pipe_cmd`.

When program named `pipe_cmd` is running, I can see the all the information about the processes on the remote computer, which is as expected.

But when I hit `h` key, I can see such help message on my ***local terminal***, which is really ***out of my expectation***. Here is what I see:

```
Help for Interactive Commands - procps-ng version 3.3.9
Window 1:Def: Cumulative mode Off.  System: Delay 0.1 secs; Secure mode Off.

  Z,B,E,e   Global: 'Z' colors; 'B' bold; 'E'/'e' summary/task memory scale
  l,t,m     Toggle Summary: 'l' load avg; 't' task/cpu stats; 'm' memory info
  0,1,2,3,I Toggle: '0' zeros; '1/2/3' cpus or numa node views; 'I' Irix mode
  f,F,X     Fields: 'f'/'F' add/remove/order/sort; 'X' increase fixed-width

  L,&,<,> . Locate: 'L'/'&' find/again; Move sort column: '<'/'>' left/right
  R,H,V,J . Toggle: 'R' Sort; 'H' Threads; 'V' Forest view; 'J' Num justify
  c,i,S,j . Toggle: 'c' Cmd name/line; 'i' Idle; 'S' Time; 'j' Str justify
  x,y     . Toggle highlights: 'x' sort field; 'y' running tasks
  z,b     . Toggle: 'z' color/mono; 'b' bold/reverse (only if 'x' or 'y')
  u,U,o,O . Filter by: 'u'/'U' effective/any user; 'o'/'O' other criteria
  n,#,^O  . Set: 'n'/'#' max tasks displayed; Show: Ctrl+'O' other filter(s)
  C,...   . Toggle scroll coordinates msg for: up,down,left,right,home,end

  k,r       Manipulate tasks: 'k' kill; 'r' renice
  d or s    Set update interval
  W,Y       Write configuration file 'W'; Inspect other output 'Y'
  q         Quit
          ( commands shown with '.' require a visible task display window ) 
Press 'h' or '?' for help with Windows,
```

What a surprise! The aforementioned behaviour looks like the `top` command is directly called in my local bash, but it's really called by `popen`.

I am really confused now. Could somebody shed some light on this matter?

***Note***:

The IP address(i.e. `192.168.1.51`) in the code snippet is my local computer's IP. But I don't think it's the reason why the program should work in this way.

I will try to run this program on another computer right now.

***UPDATED***:

Some phenomena when this program runs on another computer whose IP address is different without any modification for the aforementioned code snippet.

How to solve this problem? I don't want the `stdin` of current process influence the behaviour of the shell command. One method that I know is to use `pipe` & `fork` and close the `stdin`. Any better way to achieve this goal with `popen`?

Comment: `popen` connects the stdout to your process. But stdin is unchanged. So the child process is reading stdin just as it normally would. From the [popen manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html): "*the command's
       standard input is the same as that of the process that called
       popen().*"

Comment: 'Current progress'? Do yo mean current *process?*

Comment: @kaylum Any reference? I have carefully read the manual, but I really don't see such saying, indeed. And what's more, how to solve this problem? I don't want the `stdin` of current process influence the behaviour of the shell command. One method that I know is to use pipe and close the `stdin`. Any better way to achieve this goal when still uses `popen`?

Comment: I added the reference to my first comment already.

Comment: if you need to use stdin and stdout (stderr) with your sub process, you should probably use fork and bind in/out accordingly

Comment: @kaylum 1. If I understand you correctly, the `stdin` is shared by the process that called `popen()` and the command itself.  2. If that is right, neither  the process that called `open()`  nor the command itself is guaranteed to read complete data which is sent to the `stdin` because they compete with each other. If I miss something, please let me know.

Comment: "*because they compete with each other*". Yes that is the case. If you run two programs concurrently that both read from stdin then yes they will compete. That is the nature of concurrent processes. It is up to the coder to prevent that if that is the desired behaviour. That is, yes you need the parent process to redirect the stdin of the child process if that is the behaviour you want.

Comment: @kaylum If I understand you correctly, you intend to say the parent process need to ***redirect*** the stdin ***to*** the child process. As far as I can see, it seems this goal could not be achieved by using `popen`, because the manual says the stdin is shared between them and it seems no way to redirect the `stdin`. If I miss something, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same manual:

> reading from the stream reads the command's standard output, and the command's standard input is the same as that of the process that called popen()

The command you are executing is `ssh`. It tries to read from the same terminal you are running your program from. This creates a race, but since the program doesn't read anything, `ssh` always wins. Then `ssh` passes your input to the remote program which interprets it.

You can redirect the standard input of the command being executed with normal shell syntax

```
FILE* file = popen("... < /dev/null", "r");
```

but this will not work with `top` and other interactive commands that expect their standard input to be a terminal.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  1. If I understand you correctly, the `stdin` is shared by the process that called `popen()` and the command itself.  2. If that is right, neither  the process that called `open()`  nor the command itself is guaranteed to read complete data which is sent to the `stdin` because they compete with each other. If I miss something, please let me know.

Comment: This is exactly correct.

Comment: ***this will not work with top and other interactive commands that expect their standard input to be a terminal.***   If I understand you correctly, it seems this goal could not be achieved by using `popen`, because the manual says the `stdin` is shared between processes and it ***seems no way to redirect the `stdin`*** (i.e. for `top`). If I miss something, please let me know.

Comment: @John `top` wants a terminal and refuses to work without one. There is no way to make it not so. You need a terminal, and you need to make it the standard input of `top` somehow. If you redirect the standard input to say `dev/null`, with `popen` or otherwise, `top` will not work. The only way to make `top` not read from your terminal is to redirect it to *another* terminal.

Comment: ***The only way to make top not read from your terminal is to give it another terminal.*** How to achieve this goal?

Comment: Read about pseudoterminals. You need to create a master-slave pair with `openpty`, give the slave part to your interactive program, and leave the master part alone. You probably want to use `fork/exec` with it, but if you really want to, you can use `popen` and shell redirection like this: `sprintf(cmd, "yourcommand < %s", ptsname(master)); file = popen(cmd, "r");`